# Undefined array key "password" in LoginController (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to customize my login but it throws me the error that appears in the title.

This is the function in the `LoginController`:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
  $request->validate([
    'username' => 'required|string|email',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    'remember' => 'boolean',
  ]);

  #:: Undefined array key "password"
  if ($this->guard()->attempt(['a_username' => $request->username, 'a_password' => $request->password], $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
  }

  return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

The question why I use these custom columns and not the ones that come with laravel by default. Is that I have 2 tables that are used to authenticate.

In my database I have the columns: `a_username` (it is the email)
`a_password` (is the password)

This is the login form:

```
<form class="js-validation-signin" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt py-4" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt py-4" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```

Thank you for your patience as I have to translate this problem from Spanish to English. :)

Comment: I'm also having hard time customizing my login because my login credentials were user_name and user_pass and using other Model for login. I will appreciate if you could lend some help. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eloquent user provider contain this code

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];
   
    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

So to override default functionality you need:

1. In your user model add (override) method `getAuthPassword`

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->a_password;
}
```

2. Update your code (change `a_password` to `password`):

```
 if ($this->guard()->attempt(['a_username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
  }
```